# Try to render two templates in same View (Ui-Router)

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to render two templates at the same time in same View using two differents ui-view. I'm probably missing something but I don't know what. Can I get some help ?

My App.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider) {

  //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  var People = {
    name: 'People',
    url: '/People',
    views: {
      'PeopleView': {
        templateUrl: 'People.html'
      }
    }

  }

  var Company = {
    name: 'Company',
    url: '/Company',
    views: {
      'CompanyView': {
        templateUrl: 'Company.html'
      }
    }
  }

  $stateProvider.state(People);
  $stateProvider.state(Company);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <legend>Content</legend>
      <div ui-view="PeopleView" class="col col-md-4"></div>
      <div ui-view="CompanyView" class="col col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

[Full Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZJcZr8MK2Tsyqy7phJr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you need to achieve, but I guess that you should put both your views into the same state and work on within it

```
$stateProvider.state('mainState', {
    views: {
      'CompanyView': {
        templateUrl: 'Company.html'
      },
      'PeopleView': {
        templateUrl: 'People.html'
      }
    }
})
```

I've edited your plunk to illustrate what I mean - http://plnkr.co/edit/V0lF78MZhrOnwXF7F6Ih?p=preview

Comment: Hi Fedor, how are you ? After I get your solution to my web app, i'm having another issue with my router. This approach will render all Views when the state is called. Do you know if is there a way to render only the called view ? Or if has some lazyload to use ? I made another topic to this question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179394/lazyload-to-multiple-views-in-ui-router