# Lazyload to multiple views in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, state

A few months ago I've be created the topic: [Try to render two templates in same View (Ui-Router)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268849/try-to-render-two-templates-in-same-view-ui-router), where I asked about how to render multiple views in the same page. My objective with this was created a web app as an desktop one, with views to minimize, maximize, close and stuff like that.

Well, my app is ready but I'm getting a problem, when I up my app to the production some computers are taking a long time to render all the Views. In the image bellow we can se a lot of requisitions that server take to return my templatesURL's.

[image: My View Templates]

There is a way to avoid this ? I was looking for an lazy load to templateURL but I Didn't find any. :(

[This plunkr was the approach what I used](http://plnkr.co/edit/V0lF78MZhrOnwXF7F6Ih?p=preview). I have only one state for all my Views (My current app.config has 103 Views):

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('mainState', {
    views: {
      'CompanyView': {
        templateUrl: 'Company.html'
      },
      'PeopleView': {
        templateUrl: 'People.html'
      },
     .....
     ....
    }
  })


});
```

Comment: Do you mean eager loading which loads all the templates before they are used?

Comment: Yes, that or load only the template from the called view.

Comment: I think you have chosen the wrong approach, the proper way to do it would be something like dynamic tabs, were you can add `n` tabs of your choice, using ui-router like that will make it load all views, because it has to.

Comment: By default angular will only fetch views that are needed, aka lazy loading. To load all templates before app start, you'll need to compile all templates into a single js file. Tools like [ng-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-templates) will help you do that.

Comment: @Icycool In this case ui-state will render all views, if it has 100 views, it'll be all loaded because it's on the same route/state.

Comment: @FábioCarvalho, how does your pages look like? Is it a component, or a template with ng-controller?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro It's a template with ng-controller.

Comment: @lcycool as Lenilson said, all the views will be load because of the state. But I will give look in this ng-template, thank you.

Comment: ng-template will cache the views for you, so that you don't need to download them, but still, sadly ui-router will load them all. It might optimize a little bit, but not sure how effective that would be.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap tabs or what? How does your pages look like in the page? Windows, tabs, panels or what?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I created my own JS and CSS files with bootstrap. Currently they look like Windows as the followed print: imgur.com/S827PVv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

The way you approached the solution is the cause of the problem you're facing, because you have too many views for a single state, it'll end up having to load all of them in order to set that state, so every time you access your state, `ui-router` has to load every template in order to set the views. It might not cause problem for a few number of templates, but, for larger numbers like yours it is definitely an issue.

### Ng-Templates

You can try to cache your templates in your page using `<script type="text/ng-template"...` in order to prevent the loading time, it's a good practice by the way. Usually it's part of the production build optimization, load all templates in the template cache, so that the application load time decreases significantly provided that you don't have to wait for an http call to load a page. It will indeed increase the performance in your case, but I don't have a benchmark that ensure if it'd be enough for your scenario.

### Component Based Solution

Anyhow, you can always implement interface components to behave the way you want, optimized in such a way that it doesn't have to load one hundred templates to show a single panel for the user.

My suggestion is, instead of using `ui-router`, use a component based solution, create a directive component to hold the panel content of each window and its behavior; and use a controller to manage the state of opened and closed panels, holding and managing each opened panel in a list and so on. For example:

```
<nav>
  <button ng-click="openPanel({title: 'My Panel Title', templateUrl: 'myPanel.html'>">
    Open myPanel
  </button>
<nav>
<main>
  <panel ng-repeat="panel in openedPanels"></panel>
</main>
```

The following snippet implements this approach using bootstrap 4 css, each panel is a bootstrap card, and it has a list of panels it can open and on click of a nav list it adds the respective panel to the opened panels list where angularjs can render it on the html using `ng-repeat`.  This way, only the opened window will be rendered, therefore, only the opened window template will be loaded.

> **Disclaimer:** This is a very simple example implemented not using the best practices available out there. If you intend to use this approach you should implement it based on your application to fit better the needs of your architecture, this one is not a complete functional component, it's just an example for the sake of the demonstration.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('PanelsCtrl', function($scope) {
  
    // available windows to be opened
    $scope.panels = [
      { title: 'Window 1', templateUrl: 'window1.html' },
      { title: 'Window 2', templateUrl: 'window2.html' }];
    
    // all currently opened panels
    $scope.openedPanels = [];
    
    // opens a panel (a.k.a, adds a panel
    //  to the opened panels list)
    $scope.openPanel = function(panel) {
      if ($scope.openedPanels.indexOf(panel) === -1)
        $scope.openedPanels.push(panel);
    };
    
    // close a panel (a.k.a, removes a panel
    //  from the opened panels list)
    $scope.onClosePanel = function(panel) {
      $scope.openedPanels.splice($scope.openedPanels.indexOf(panel), 1);
    };
  })
  .directive('window', function($templateRequest, $templateCache, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        panel: '=',
        onClosePanel: '&'
      },
      template: `
        <div class="card">
          <h4 class="card-header">
            <span>{{ panel.title }}</span>
            <button
              ng-click="onClosePanel(panel)"
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </h4>
          <div class="card-body">
           <ng-include src="panel.templateUrl"></ng-include>
          </div>
        </div>
      `
    }
  })
  // example controlelr to be used with ng-controller
  .controller('Window1Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.window1Prop = 'This is a property from Window1Ctrl'
  })
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="PanelsCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item" ng-repeat="panel in panels">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#" ng-click="openPanel(panel)">
            {{ panel.title }}
          </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <window ng-repeat="panel in openedPanels" panel="panel" on-close-panel="onClosePanel(panel)">
        </window>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- NG-TEMPLATES -->
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="window1.html">
    <div ng-controller="Window1Ctrl">
      <b>{{panel.title}}</b>
      <h5>window1Prop: {{ window1Prop }}</p>
    </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="window2.html">
    <em>{{panel.title}}</em>
  </script>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lenilson, Thank You very much! This is what I've been looking for a long time to use in this project. We use ui-router here because we didn't find anything who look's like what we want to do.